# what does (!!!) means in R and how to rename a set of variables

Tags: r

I saw a code like this:

```
df %>% rename(!!! setNames(map$VarName, map$StdName))
```

what does `!!!` means here? also, why we use `rename` and `setNames` together? And if df has less variables than map$VarName, is it a way to let this codes runs? right now it will pop error message `Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.`

Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: You probably want to check out [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: `!!!` or big bang operator is used to splice a list, so that every element of a list is now a single argument. We often use it when we want to apply a function to a `list` of arguments. With regard to the code above I can't pass a judgment unless I see a reproducible piece of your data by `dput(head(data))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, there are some column names that didn't exist from the key/val dataset.  With the current code, one option is to `subset/filter the 'map' dataset with the columns that are common in 'df'

```
map1 <- subset(map, VarName %in% colnames(df))
```

and then use the subset dataset with splicing notation (`!!!`) on the named vector

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rename(!!! setNames(map1$VarName, map1$StdName))
```

Instead of `!!!`, we can use `rename_with`  as well

```
df %>%
    rename_with(~ map1$StdName, all_of(map1$VarName))
```